# Redis: moving data from an index to another

Tags: redis

What is the way to migrate the data from DB 0 to DB 1 in the same instance of Redis?

I have found many resources about migrating from one instance to another (SAVE or replication), but not from one index to another; maybe I don't use the correct search keywords…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands [COPY](http://redis.io/commands/copy) and [MOVE](http://redis.io/commands/move) let's you copy/move keys from one DB to another.